# Can the morning after pill affect your body temperature?

Tags: obstetrics, sex, contraception

It's not something I can find much information about online... but is it possible that the MAP could send your hormones out of whack and result in feeling really warm at times?

Comment: Requests for personal medical advice are off topic here, so I edited your question to fit our rules. I hope you understand.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised, as I know that some fertility treatments cause hot flashes. // Why not ask a pharmacist?